# Not displaying user role from session data

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the users role from the session data but when ever I attempt I get an error saying

> Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to
> function getUserAccessRoleByID(), 1 passed in
> G:\xampp\htdocs\highballSystem\index.php on line 7 and exactly 2
> expected in
> G:\xampp\htdocs\highballSystem\includes\functions.inc.php:117 Stack
> trace: #0 G:\xampp\htdocs\highballSystem\index.php(7):
> getUserAccessRoleByID(NULL) #1 {main} thrown in
> G:\xampp\htdocs\highballSystem\includes\functions.inc.php on line 117.

The user role is loaded from a column in my users table in my MySQL database. The roles are stored in a sperate table tbl_user_role. Any help would be appreciated. I've tried looking around for a fix but really couldn't find anything that made sense.

**Functions.php**

```
function loginUser ($conn, $username, $pwd){
    $uidExists = uidExists($conn, $username, $username);

    if ($uidExists === false) {
        header("location: ../login.php?error=wronglogin");
        exit();
    }

    $pwdHashed = $uidExists ['usersPwd'];
    $checkPwd = password_verify($pwd, $pwdHashed);
    if ($checkPwd === false) {
        header("location: ../login.php?error=wronglogin");
        exit();
    }else if ($checkPwd === true) {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION["userid"] = $uidExists ["usersId"];
            $_SESSION["useruid"] = $uidExists ["usersUid"];

            header("location: ../index.php");
            exit();
    } 
}

function getUserAccessRoleByID($id)
{
    $sql = "SELECT user_role FROM tbl_user_role WHERE id = ?;";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
 if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
    header("location: signup.php?error=stmtfailed");
        exit();
 }
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $id);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    $resultData = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultData)) {
        return $row;
    }
    else{
        $result = false;
        return $result;
    }
}
```

**Index.php**

```
<?php 
include_once 'header.php';
?>
<?php  
                    if (isset($_SESSION["useruid"])) {
                        echo "<p>Hello there " . $_SESSION["useruid"] . "</p>";
                        echo "You are logged in as <strong>". getUserAccessRoleByID($_SESSION['user_role'])."</strong>";
                    }
                ?>
<?php 
include_once 'footer.php';
?>
```

Comment: what is value of `$_SESSION['user_role']`

Comment: @gaurav It should be the role name from the tbl_user_role table.

Comment: are you sure that you are not defining two times `getUserAccessRoleByID` function because error is suggesting it require two arguments but code which you have share only have one argument

Comment: @gaurav its only defined in the one place in the functions.php file

Comment: but error is showing Too few arguments to function `getUserAccessRoleByID()`, **1** passed in G:\xampp\htdocs\highballSystem\index.php on line 7 and exactly **2** expected in , again i will suggest you to check 117 line in `functions.inc.php`

Comment: Ok now its breaking after this if statement if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
    header("location: signup.php?error=stmtfailed");
        exit();

Comment: so arguments problem is solved ?  it's breaking because error is showing value of `$_SESSION['user_role']` is `NULL` is that line in error G:\xampp\htdocs\highballSystem\index.php(7): getUserAccessRoleByID(**NULL**) #1 {main}

Comment: I think so, I added ```echo "You are logged in as <strong>". getUserAccessRoleByID($_SESSION["usersRole"],$_SESSION["id"])."</strong>";``` to line 7 and the error went away. I'm not sure that's the solution though

Comment: now i will suggest check your session values .